# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression : no unused expression

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
import Alert from '@material-ui/lab/Alert';
export default function MyComponent(props) {
let [disabled] = useState(false);
const calculateTotal = event => {
        if (!disabled) {
            disabled = true;
            calTotal().then(validateResult => {
                disabled = false;
            });
        } }


       { return(
        disabled && (
            <Alert severity="warning"> Previous request is in progress!!! </Alert>
        )
    )}

    };
```

}
Using return functionality works but I lose the warning message all together

Comment: You need to return JSX so it can be rendered.  You can't just inline JSX.

Comment: @jack.benson edited the code but i loose materialui alert message

Comment: You need to pass the returned JSX to a rendering method, like `ReactDOM.render`.  Is your JSX being passed to one somewhere in your component tree?

Comment: I updated the example code in my answer to include a MUI Alert.  See the example link.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the JSX to a rendering engine.  I put together an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-haibt-0cue3?file=/src/App.js):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

// If I tried to execute this line it would fail (see the Problems tab)
<App />;

// But this works (because you need an engine to render JSX)
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

If you are rendering in a component, you need to return the JSX:

```
const Test = () => (
  <Alert>My Alert</Alert>
)

// or more verbosely

const Test2 = () => {
  return <Alert>My Alert</Alert>
}
```

Hope that helps!